# Cancelling an errant merge

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, merge

Simple (and probably dumb) question, but here goes:

I wanted to merge my Dev code to the QA\Main branch (where it belonged) but accidentally chose the QA branch (where there is no code.)  Now the Resolve conflicts have a couple hundred "The item has been deleted in the target branch."  How do I cancel the merge?  Or do I resolve the conflict by taking the target version for all?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't checked in the merge, then just undo all of the pending changes.

From the pending changes window in Team Explorer select the root folder and right click, then choose undo.

If you have checked in the merge then you'll need to rollback the change.

From the root of the target branch in Source Control explorer, right click and select view history. Select the changeset that represents the merge and select "Rollback" or "Rollback Entire Changeset" Then check in the changes.